# Why my C program is failed to detect the special characters?

Tags: c

I have written a C program to detect input types. It detects alphabets and digits well but it is detecting special characters as digits. Please help me to solve the question.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') printf("Alphabet of lower case.");
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') printf("Alphabet of upper case.");
    else if (c >= 0 || c < 0) printf("Digit");
    else printf("Special character.");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program:

[image]

Comment: `if (c >= 0 || c < 0)` ... think about it ... it's the same as `if (c exists)`; you want `if (('0' <= c) && (c <= '9'))` or, better, `if (isdigit((unsigned char)c))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please tke the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- When you post input or output that is text, please copy the text as such, don't use screenshots.

Comment: @pmg Why would you cast a `char` to an `unsigned char` if `isdigit` takes an `int`? I do agree with using `isdigit` and suggest replacing the first checks with `islower` and `isupper`.

Comment: @Cheatah: because `isdigit("café"[3])` invokes UB (but `isdigit((unsigned char)"café"[3])` doesn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, numbers are chars! 
You could try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') printf("Alphabet of lower case.");
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') printf("Alphabet of upper case.");
    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') printf("Digit");
    else printf("Special character.");
    return 0;
}
```

It was failing because you were comparing chars against numbers